# How to delete a node in a binary search tree using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree, recursive-datastructures

I have now been trying to formulate a deletion function for deleting a node inside a binary search tree given that the node contains the content being searched for. I have wrote the skeleton for the function that does the search for the content and returns true or false depending on if it found it or not. The issue is that I cannot seem to get how to implement the actual deletion part for my function. If the root node contains the value I am looking for, I do not know how to assign one of the old root's children the root position after deletion. I am also having a hard time figuring out how to NULL the children pointers after deletion of a node and relinking parts of the tree that could potentially be severed if I just disconnect the node that contains the value being searched.

Below is the function I have so far:

```
bool BSTree::Remove(int content, BSTNode*& bst_node) const {
// makes sure the tree is not empty (function returns false if it is)  
if (bst_node != NULL) {
  // checks to see if nodes contents matches content param 
  if (bst_node->GetContents() == content) {
      // checks to see if the node has children
      if (bst_node->GetLeftChild() == NULL && bst_node->GetRightChild() == NULL) {

      } else if (bst_node->GetLeftChild() == NULL) {

      } else if (bst_node->GetRightChild() == NULL) {

      } else {

      }
      return true;
    // checks to see if the content of node is less/greater than content param
    } else if (content < bst_node->GetContents()) {
        if (bst_node->GetLeftChild() != NULL)
          return Remove(content, bst_node->GetLeftChild());
    } else if (content > bst_node->GetContents()) {
        if (bst_node->GetRightChild() != NULL)
          return Remove(content, bst_node->GetRightChild());
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

What I have added:

```
bool BSTree::Remove(int content, BSTNode*& bst_node) {
  BSTNode* parent = bst_node;
  if (bst_node == NULL) {
    return false;
  } else {
    if (content == bst_node->GetContents()) {
      if (bst_node->GetLeftChild() == NULL && bst_node->GetRightChild() == NULL) {
        if (bst_node == root_) {
          Clear();
        } else {
          // code for deleting leaf
          bst_node->SetContents(0);
          bst_node = NULL;
          delete bst_node;
          size_--;
        }
      } else if (bst_node->GetLeftChild() == NULL) {
        // code for deleting node with only right child
        if (bst_node == root_) {
          parent = bst_node->GetRightChild();
          bst_node->SetContents(0);
          bst_node = NULL;
          delete bst_node;
          root_ = parent;
        } else {

        }
        size_--;
      } else if (bst_node->GetRightChild() == NULL) {
        // code for deleting node with only left child
        if (bst_node == root_) {
          parent = bst_node->GetLeftChild();
          bst_node->SetContents(0);
          bst_node = NULL;
          delete bst_node;
          root_ = parent;
        } else {

        }
        size_--;
      } else {
        // code for deleting node with two children
        size_--;
      }
    } else if (content < bst_node->GetContents()) {
      if (bst_node->GetLeftChild() == NULL) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return Remove(content, bst_node->GetLeftChild());
      }
    } else if (content > bst_node->GetContents()) {
      if (bst_node->GetRightChild() == NULL) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return Remove(content, bst_node->GetRightChild());
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Helper function for the remove function:

```
int BSTree::FindMin(BSTNode* bst_node) const {
  if (bst_node != NULL) {
    if (bst_node->GetLeftChild() != NULL)
      return FindMin(bst_node->GetLeftChild());
    return bst_node->GetContents();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way of deleting a node is to replace it with his direct successor the delete the leaf, so that you do not break the tree invariant.

The successor of a node is the leftmost child of its right subtree, so once you get to the node you want to delete, search for the successor and swap the nodes. Once it's done, search for the leaf and removes it. As you took the leftmost child, you are sure that the leaf will have a NULL left child. It It has a right child, replace the leaf with the right child and that's it.

A usual implementation used for binary search tree is to make `Remove` return a Node, so you can reshape the tree just by returning the nodes, and don't have to bother with grandchildren cases.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I do understand the way it should be deleted. my issue is keeping the parent node of a node I want to delete in order to re link the subtree that is left in the process of deleting a node with 1 or 2 children.